# can we replace the search box controls with standard controls without using a "Feature"?

Tags: search, branding

In sharepoint 2010,

can we just add a text box and a button to the master page, and when the button gets a click it queries the regular sharepoint search page and pass the barameters?

if yes what parameters should we pass? and how?

thanks SPs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Just right click the page and view the source specific to the SharePoint search box. Now you need to note down the names of the JS functions used in there.

Further add you own input box and incorporate the same JS functions on the same events as used by the OOB SharePoint serach box. You can also add your own functions like adding ghost text etc..